# Load the node as EntityInterface not NodeInterface

Tags: nodes

`hook_node_insert(NodeInterface $node)` gets a `NodeInterface` parameter. I need to pass it to
`mymodule_node_operations(EntityInterface $entity)` which accepts an `EntityInterface` parameter.

How do I load this node as `EntityInterface` type? Basically I need to downcast to the parent class which is Entity.

This is the error I get when attempting to pass `$node` to the function as `NodeInterface`.

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to mymodule_node_operations() must be an instance of EntityInterface, instance of Drupal\node\Entity\Node given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not include the required class. I added the following to get it to work:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/class/Node/8.8.x) has [EntityBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityBase.php/class/EntityBase/8.8.x) in its hierarchy. EntityBase implements [EntityInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/interface/EntityInterface/8.8.x). This means you can pass a Node to a function that expects EntityInterface, since Node extends a class that implements that interface. This is how OOP works, and why classes are type hinted with interfaces (eg. EntityInterface) rather than a specific class (eg. EntityBase).

Comment: Perhaps you don't have `use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;` in your code?

Comment: @anonymous You are absolutely right!!! Thank you :)